# Should I use an updater function and const in a useCallBack or a let variable?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, usecallback

Both of the following work and the child component doesn't rerender, but which one is preferable and why?

This one using a `const` and an updater function

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(c => c + 1)
}, [])
```

Or this one using a `let` and a `++` operator

```
let [count, setCount] = useState(0)
const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count++)
}, [])
```

Comment: Always `const` since the only way to change its value should be using `setCount`, never changing it "manually"